# How to use Java reflection to set interface field

Tags: java, reflection, jboss, jboss7.x

I'm using Jboss 7.1.1.final and i have an application with heavy use of JMS. After doing some performance tests i see that whenever i reach a certain amount of messages the application starts to fail since there are not enough queue sessions.

After some research i discovered that this JMS attribute is only exposed in jboss version 7.1.2 (see [here](https://community.jboss.org/message/741062#741062)) .

Since, for legal reasons, i can't currently use this version (or the specific build where it was fixed) , the only other way to change it is by using reflection. So i downloaded Jboss source code and started playing with it, now i have a few questions:

First of all i discovered the class i need is `org.jboss.as.messaging.CommonAttributes` which is actually an interface and it has this line :

```
 SimpleAttributeDefinition CONNECTION_THREAD_POOL_MAX_SIZE = new SimpleAttributeDefinition("thread-pool-max-size",
        new ModelNode().set(HornetQClient.DEFAULT_THREAD_POOL_MAX_SIZE), ModelType.INT,  true, MeasurementUnit.NONE);
```

1. Will `ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader()` give me the classLoader i need in order to load the class?
2. How do i set an interface field value using reflection? (the `Field.set()` method requires an object instance and since it is an interface i cannot instantiate it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are talking about [this](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.jboss.as/jboss-as-messaging/7.1.1.Final/org/jboss/as/messaging/CommonAttributes.java#CommonAttributes.0CONNECTION_THREAD_POOL_MAX_SIZE) piece of code. I must disappoint you: interfaces don't have fields, at all. They only have method declarations, without implementation.

What you see there are actually `public static final` (all these keywords are implicit for "fields" inside interfaces) constants defined within interface body. But the interface is only used as a namespace for them, they aren't *real* fields. Classes implementing such interface aren't inheriting these fields and having their own variable copy. They are only constants.

That being said - you cannot do anything, at least with this interface.